# Queryset with values filtered from another queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

If I have a queryset qs1 like this:

```
<QuerySet [{u'name': u'John', u'birthdate': u'1980-01-01'}, 
           {u'name': u'Larry', u'birthdate': u'1976-12-28'}, 
            .....']}
```

I need to use all values associated with key 'name' from qs1 to query another model and get qs2 like this:

```
<QuerySet [{u'student_name': u'John', u'grade': u'A'}, 
           {u'student_name': u'Larry', u'grade': u'B'}, 
            .....']}
```

After this, I have to combine qs1 and qs2 so the final_qs like this:

```
[{u'name': u'John',u'birthdate': u'1980-01-01', u'grade': u'A'}, 
 {u'student_name': u'Larry', u'birthdate': u'1976-12-28', u'grade': u'B'}, 
  .....']}
```

How would I achieve this?
I have code like this:

```
qs1 = Person.objects.values('name', 'birthdate')
for t in qs1:
     qs2 = Grades.objects.filter(student_name=t['name'])
                               .values('student_name', 'grade')
```

My qs1 looks OK. However, my qs2 becomes this:

```
<QuerySet [{u'student_name': u'John', u'grade': u'A'}]>
<QuerySet [{u'student_name': u'Larry', u'grade': u'B'}]>
```

Because of qs2, I am not able use zip(qs1, qs2) to construct final_qs the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

I would aggregate all `qs1` names to a list:

```
names = [t['name'] for t in qs1]
```

And then execute the following query:

```
qs2 = Grades.objects.filter(student_name__in=names)
                           .values('student_name', 'grade')
```

The latter would select only the rows where `student_name` is in the `names` from the `qs1` and should return a single `QuerySet` with all matching rows.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly for qs2. However, when I do this:queryset = [x + y[1:] for (x, y) in zip(qs1, qs2)]. I am getting 'TypeError: unhashable type'.

Comment: yes, because you are slicing dictionary, what exactly are you trying to do with this `y[1:]`? You can find similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929234/python-appending-dictionary-typeerror-unhashable-type)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your Grade model contains the `ForeignKey(Person)` which means that there is a reverse relation created. Which means that you can ["follow the relationship backwards"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) and all sorts of other django magic.

So given you have a queryset `qs1` of `Person`s:

```
>>> qs1.values('student_name', 'birthdate', 'grade_set__grade')
```

The aforementioned magic can be observed by this mysterious `'grade_set__grade'`.

Django has actually added another field to you `Person` model: `.grade_set`. This would be all the grades that have the belong to that person instance. We can then access all those grades via djangos double underscore notation that we use in filters.

You can quickly try that out by doing `User.objects.last().grade_set`

**Bonus**

Don't like the term 'grade_set', prefer something else? You can change this in the Grade model.

```
   class Grade(models.Model):
       # some fields
       ForeignKey(Person, related_name='all_their_grades')
       # other fields
```

You can now do `User.objects.last().all_their_grades` to do the same as before. Please ntoe that once you change it, the `.grade_set` is no longer available.